# Skip rows based on LAG Column (Pack Intervals)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have written a SQL Query to calculate start and end times for events.
The result looks like this: (i saved it as `TimeData`)

```
Id        start        end
___________________________
1        100        124
2        106        115
3        127        130
4        128        130
5        136        150
```

**These rows are ordered by 'start'.**

What I want to do now is to collapse all these rows to represent the time-spans that contain data.
Something like this:

```
start        end
________________
100        124
127        130
136        150
```

What I accomplished so far (but is horribly wrong) is like this:

```
select * from 

(select *,
LAG([end],1) over(order by [start]) as pe
from TimeData) as X

where X.pe < [start]
```

This actually works for some subsequent rows but it keeps `pe` from the previous row in `TimeData`, while I required it to come from from **the previous returning row** (previous row that where condition was true for it).

I hope my question is clear.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem looks like the problem that Itzik Ben-Gan called [Packing Intervals](http://blogs.solidq.com/en/sqlserver/packing-intervals). In his article he shows a method that should be more efficient than self-join shown in another answer.

See his article for detailed explanation of how it works. Run the query step-by-step, CTE-by-CTE and examine intermediate results to understand how it works.

**Sample data**

```
DECLARE @T TABLE(ID int, starttime int, endtime int);

INSERT INTO @T VALUES
(1, 100, 124),
(2, 106, 115),
(3, 127, 130),
(4, 128, 130),
(5, 136, 150);
```

**Query**

```
WITH 
C1 AS
(
    SELECT ID, starttime AS ts, +1 AS type, 1 AS sub
    FROM @T
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ID, endtime AS ts, -1 AS type, 0 AS sub
    FROM @T
)
,C2 AS
(
    SELECT C1.*,
        SUM(type) 
            OVER(ORDER BY ts, type DESC
            ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) 
        - sub AS cnt
    FROM C1
)
,C3 AS
(
    SELECT ID, ts,
        (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ts) - 1) / 2 + 1
        AS grpnum
    FROM C2
    WHERE cnt = 0
)
SELECT MIN(ts) AS starttime, MAX(ts) AS endtime
FROM C3
GROUP BY grpnum;
```

**Result**

```
+-----------+---------+
| starttime | endtime |
+-----------+---------+
|       100 |     124 |
|       127 |     130 |
|       136 |     150 |
+-----------+---------+
```

Comment: This method can have issues if there are ties dates on the same days.

Comment: Hi @GordonLinoff, could you show an example that would lead to incorrect result of the query. I don't quite understand what you mean by "same days". The `start` and `end` are just `int`. Feel free to edit my answer if needed. Thanks.

Comment: Simple.  If you have 100/124 repeated twice, you are not guaranteed to get zero for the final sum.  Sorting in SQL is not stable, and the results do not have to be consistent, event from one row to the next.  Similarly, the results can be inconsistent for 100/101 and 101/102.

Comment: Sorry, @GordonLinoff, I still don't get it. Are you talking about `SUM(type) OVER(ORDER BY ts, type DESC ... )`? It would merge all overlapping intervals. If there are two intervals `[100, 101)` and `[101, 102)` they will be merged into one `[100, 102)`. Guaranteed. It is assumed that intervals are closed-open. I think that `ORDER BY ts, type DESC` is enough to guarantee correct running total even with repeating values for `start` and/or `end`. Specifically, `type DESC` is important.

Answer (score 1):

Rather painful.  One method is to determine which records start a new interval. You have to be careful with `lag()`, because the overlap may not be on the exactly preceding record.

Here is one method:

```
with t as (
      select t.*,
             (case when exists (select 1
                                from t t2
                                where t.start <= t2.end and t.start >= t2.start and
                                      t2.id < t.id
                               )
                   then 0 else 1
               end) as startgrp
      from t
     )
select grp, min(start), max(end)
from (select t.*, sum(startgrp) over (order by start) as grp
      from t
     ) t
group by grp;
```

Comment: I'll try it as soon as I can. Will respond :) thanks

Comment: @AliJey, your problem looks like the problem that Itzik Ben-Gan called [Packing Intervals](http://blogs.solidq.com/en/sqlserver/packing-intervals). In his article he shows a method that should be more efficient than self-join shown in this answer.